# Xtext grammar that matches any input between certain xml tags

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, freemarker, xtext

I am trying to write a very simple Xtext grammar for the freemarker language. I am failing at matching any text between known tags.

My grammar thus far:

```
grammar org.github.FreemarkerEditor with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate freemarkerEditor "http://www.github.org/FreemarkerEditor"

Freemarker:
    elements+=Element*;

Element: Tag|Print|Comment|Text;

Print:value=PRINT_CONTENT;
Tag:open=TAG_OPEN elements+=Element* TAG_CLOSE;

Text: text+=ANY_OTHER+;

Comment: text=COMMENT_CONTENT;

terminal PRINT_START_FRAGMENT:'${';
terminal PRINT_CONTENT:PRINT_START_FRAGMENT->'}';
terminal COMMENT_START:'<#--';
terminal COMMENT_CONTENT:COMMENT_START->'-->';
terminal TAG_START_FRAGMENT:'<#';
terminal TAG_OPEN:TAG_START_FRAGMENT->'>';
terminal TAG_CLOSE_START:'</#';
terminal TAG_CLOSE:TAG_CLOSE_START->'>';
```

It should work like this: There are 4 types of elements that can occur in any order and number in a document. Freemarker tags that always start with `<#tag some text and functions called>` `</#tag>` which can again contain any elements. Comments which should contain all the text in between ignoring anything in there: `<#-- Comment -->`. There are also simple print statements that look like this: `${some variable or method call}`. Everything else, even normal xml tags or curly brackets should be unparsed text.

The problem in my grammar seems to be that it is not able to match text anywhere. The example input

```
${hallo.welt} 
mhh
<#list something as somethingElse>${aha haha} some text </#list>
```

shows an error at `mhh` stating that an EOF is missing. How do I have to change the grammar to work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i generate your Grammar i get

```
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl4/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl4/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:297:1: Decision can match input such as "RULE_ANY_OTHER" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl4.ui/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl4/ui/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:194:28: Decision can match input such as "RULE_ANY_OTHER" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

thus your grammar is ambigous and you should fix that e.g. by saying that Text should eat up as much as it can ( syntactic predicate )

```
Text: => text+=ANY_OTHER+;
```

Then there are Other Terminal that are Higher Ranked as ANY_OTHER
e.g. ID

you have to respect that as well

```
Text: => text+=(ID|ANY_OTHER)+;
```

Comment: That was the problem. It seems because it had the possibility to create as many Text Elements as it wanted to it did not match any. Thanks. Now I can create a cleaner version of the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you write your grammar the way you do? Anyway, it is your grammar.

It took me a while to figure out the problems of your grammar, however I have found a solution for your problem.

First problem: **The `Text` rule**: Since it is an infinite long input which can be matched into it, you have to take care that it is impossible for a `Text` rule followed by a `Text`rule.

Second problem: **The `Text` rule** It seems to be a String without qoute signs.

Third problem: **The `terminal` rules containing `->`**: This is too ambiguous.

I have completely rebuilt your grammar, but in my workbench it works. Maybe it does what you want:

```
Freemarker:
    elements+=Text?
    (elements+=Element
    elements+=Text?)*;

Element:
    Tag | Print | Comment;


Tag:
    '<#' open=ID content=MyString '>' elements=Freemarker '</#' close=ID '>';

MyString:
    ID ('.' | ID)*;

Print:
    '${' content=MyString '}';

Text returns Element:
    text=MyString;

Comment:
    {Comment} '<#--' -> '-->';
```

As you can see, the `Text` rule is not accessable with the `Element`rule, but Element is its super type. And any `Text` element has to followed by an Element which is not of type `Text`.

A `Text` element starts with an `ID`, followed by a `.` or an `ID`, followed by ... I think you can extend this by any other sign, but you have to try.

Then, for my oppionion it is better to have more attributes instead of anything. This makes it a lot easier to work with the model.

---

If you have any problems with recursion or any ambiguity, there is a very helpful tool available, called *ANTLRWorks*. It can visualize problems of your grammar. To use this tool, there is a optional fragment which can be included into the MWE2 workflow which builds a clean ANTLR grammar file:

```
fragment = parser.antlr.DebugAntlrGeneratorFragment {}
```

Comment: This solution limits the possible input values a lot. The whole problem is that MyString should allow everything but the symbols that open/close something, e.g. in a Text there should be curly brackets allowed.

Comment: you have to enlist them all, or do not inherit from terminals